# how to add user in supergroup of hdfs in linux?

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I was working on hdfs then i found something that permissions checks are not performed for the super-user.
If my linux user is sandy and i want add sandy to group of super-user. 
So permissions denied will not occur, is it feasible to do that in hdfs configuration.
And if there is no problem in assigning the user to supergroup then how to do it ?

Answer (score 15):

Yes , now i have whole idea how users and group should be created on any hdfs cluster.
First of all i didn't find any group named **supergroup** in **`/etc/group`**.

So good practice is to create your own supergroup.

1. sudo addgroup testgroup
2. Then create users as many you want. e.g **adduser sandy**
3. Then add these users to testgroup
4. Then edit hdfs-site.xml property and add this property 
   **dfs.permissions.superusergroup**, value will be your group name
5. Now you can create any number of folders in hdfs and then assign ownership as
   yourusername:supergroup e.g **sandy:testgroup**

Comment: FYI, use `groupadd` on centos/rhel

Answer (score 2):

Its not a good pratice to run jobs as super-user.
Be advised to create a new group and new account for hadoop/hdfs and then give required permissions as below

```
$ sudo addgroup hadoop
$ sudo adduser --ingroup hadoop hduser

$ sudo chown hduser:hadoop {directory path}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the user to hadoop group.

$ sudo adduser --ingroup hadoop sandy

Comment: is it feasible to add that user in supergroup or is it considering the user access policies of hadoop ?

Comment: To add user to super user group

$ sudo adduser <username> sudo