# Cannot Execute Hadoop Jar From PHP

Tags: java, php, hadoop

I can't execute my Hadoop jar in pseudo distributed (in case you need to see my configuration I follow this tutorial [my pseudo distributed settings](http://gaurav3ansal.blogspot.com/)) from PHP using any PHP function like `shell_exec`, `exec`, `system`. When I tried to execute jar, my browser shows a loading icon in the tab, but when I checked Hadoop app history, nothing is running. What makes it even worse is that no error message appears. I have already checked my /var/log/apache2/error.log and nothing is there.

So this is my experiment for running the code.

1. Run in the command prompt works perfectly fine.

   ```
   /usr/local/hadoop-2.9.1/bin/hadoop jar path_to_my_jar_file.jar main_class_name args
   ```

Number 2,3,4 is all the php code that I type.

2. Run using `shell_exec` nothing happens

   ```
   var_dump(shell_exec("/usr/local/hadoop-2.9.1/bin/hadoop jar path_to_my_jar_file.jar main_class_name args"));
   ```
3. Run using `exec` I got `array(0) { }`

   ```
   $retval = array();
   exec("/usr/local/hadoop-2.9.1/bin/hadoop jar path_to_my_jar_file.jar main_class_name args",$retval);
   var_dump( $retval);
   ```
4. Run using `system` I got 1

   ```
   system("/usr/local/hadoop-2.9.1/bin/hadoop jar path_to_my_jar_file.jar main_class_name args",$retval);
   var_dump( $retval);
   ```

I found this [Running MapReduce job written in Java through my PHP web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901626/running-mapreduce-job-written-in-java-through-my-php-web-page?noredirect=1&lq=1) question but I don't think I have a permission problem since I can execute this.

```
shell_exec("/usr/local/hadoop-2.9.1/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /test");
```

I even tried to change apache user but it is still not working.

Deleting this property in mapred-site.xml makes php `exec` work, but I can't see the mapreduce progress in resource manager (localhost:8088) and I also need it.

```html
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
    <description>MapReduce framework name</description>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody get the same issue it's because Hadoop configuration. I change my configuration with  [this tutorial link](https://medium.com/@nidhinmahesh/getting-started-hadoop-mapreduce-hdfs-and-yarn-configuration-and-sample-program-febb1415f945). After that you will get HDFS permision problem which can be solved by this one [how to add user in supergroup of hdfs in linux? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184306/how-to-add-user-in-supergroup-of-hdfs-in-linux).